# Is it possible to change a Party in a Corda transaction before it reaches the final stage?

Tags: corda

Is it possible to change a Party in a Corda transaction before it reaches the final stage?
A scenario where a Party is participating in a state change, and that Party leaves the organization and another Party comes in. In this case is it possible to change the Party?

Comment: >> "Party leaves the organization and another Party comes in"
What do you mean?

Comment: assuming a Party represents a user in an organisation

Answer (score 0):

Another Party would mean a different node registered to the network with a different certificate. The scenario you have in mind is not possible. You cannot start a transaction with a Party that does not exist yet, or it was not participating to the transaction from the beginning.